# WPF&MVVM: access to Controls from RelayCommand()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need both operating by mouse clicking and operating by hotkeys in my `WPF` application. User's actions affects on both data and appearance of application controls.

*For example*, the following app will send data to tea machine. You can select the tea brand, type (hot or cold) and optional ingredients: milk, lemon and syrup.

[image]

Not good from the point of view of UI design, but just example:

- If to click the dropdown menu or input `Ctrl+B`, the list of select options will appear.
- If to click the "Hot" button on input `Ctrl+T`, button becomes blue and text becomes "Cold". If to click or input `Ctrl+T` again, button becomes orange and text becomes to "Hot" again.
- If to click optional ingredient button or input respective shortcut, button's background and text becomes gray (it means "unselected"). Same action will return the respective button to active state.

[image]

If don't use `MVVM` and don't define shortcuts, the logic will be relatively simple:

```
Tea tea = new Tea(); // Assume that default settings avalible

private void ToggleTeaType(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // Change Data
    if(tea.getType().Equals("Hot")){
        tea.setType("Cold");
    }
    else{
        tea.setType("Hot");   
    }

    // Change Button Appearence
    ChangeTeaTypeButtonAppearence(sender, e);
}


private void ChangeTeaTypeButtonAppearence(object sender, EventArgs e){

    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    Style hotTeaButtonStyle = this.FindResource("TeaTypeButtonHot") as Style;
    Style coldTeaButtonStyle = this.FindResource("TeaTypeButtonCold") as Style;

    if (clickedButton.Tag.Equals("Hot")) {
        clickedButton.Style = coldTeaButtonStyle; // includes Tag declaration
        clickedButton.Content = "Cold";
    }
    else (clickedButton.Tag.Equals("Cold")) {
        clickedButton.Style = hotTeaButtonStyle; // includes Tag declaration
        clickedButton.Content = "Hot";
    }
}

// similarly for ingredients toggles
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Hot" 
            Tag="Hot"
            Click="ToggleTeaType" 
            Style="{StaticResource TeaTypeButtonHot}"/>

<Button Content="Milk" 
        Tag="True"
        Click="ToggleMilk" 
        Style="{StaticResource IngredientButtonTrue}"/>

<Button Content="Lemon" 
        Tag="True"
        Click="ToggleLemon" 
        Style="{StaticResource IngredientButtonTrue}"/>

<Button Content="Syrup" 
        Tag="True"
        Click="ToggleSyrup" 
        Style="{StaticResource IngredientButtonTrue}"/>
```

I changed my similar `WPF` project to `MVVM` because thanks to commands it's simple to assign the shortcuts:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+T" Command="{Binding ToggleTeaType}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

However, now it's a problem how to set the control's appearance. The following code is **invalid**:

```
private RelayCommand toggleTeaType;
public RelayCommand ToggleTeaType {
    // change data by MVVM methods...
    // change appearence:
    ChangeTeaTypeButtonAppearence(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

I need the Relay Commands because I can bind it to both buttons and shortcuts, but how I can access to View controls from `RelayCommand`?

Comment: Why not use the ToggleButton instead? You can then bind the IsToggled property to your data and play with it as you wish.

Comment: You can bind properties of the buttons, such as `Background` to properties of the `Tea` class.  Then use a converter to set the background colour depending on the value of the property.

Comment: Generally, I suggest you use `ToggleButton` for your scenario. Then you can use MVVM by utilizing the `IsChecked` property.

Comment: @CKII, @grek40, I did not find the `ToggleButton` control in the `WPF Controls` toolbox. Is `ToggleButton` the external library element? As I know, the `Toggle` becomes available in `UWP`...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I don't really use the toolbox, so I didn't notice. But you should be able to add the ToggleButton to the toolbox if you want: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2010/12/01/adding-missing-wpf-controls-to-the-toolbox/

Comment: @grek40, OK, anyway thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the viewmodel clean of view specific behavior. The viewmodel should just provide an interface for all relevant settings, it could look similar to the following (`BaseViewModel` would contain some helper methods to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc.):

```
public class TeaConfigurationViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TeaConfigurationViewModel()
    {
        _TeaNames = new string[]
        {
            "Lipton",
            "Generic",
            "Misc",
        };
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> _TeaNames;
    public IEnumerable<string> TeaNames
    {
        get { return _TeaNames; }
    }


    private string _SelectedTea;
    public string SelectedTea
    {
        get { return _SelectedTea; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SelectedTea, value); }
    }


    private bool _IsHotTea;
    public bool IsHotTea
    {
        get { return _IsHotTea; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _IsHotTea, value); }
    }


    private bool _WithMilk;
    public bool WithMilk
    {
        get { return _WithMilk; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _WithMilk, value); }
    }


    private bool _WithLemon;
    public bool WithLemon
    {
        get { return _WithLemon; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _WithLemon, value); }
    }


    private bool _WithSyrup;
    public bool WithSyrup
    {
        get { return _WithSyrup; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _WithSyrup, value); }
    }
}
```

As you see, there is a property for each setting, but the viewmodel doesn't care about *how* the property is assigned.

So lets build some UI. For the following example, generally suppose `xmlns:local` points to your project namespace.

I suggest utilizing a customized `ToggleButton` for your purpose:

```
public class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    static MyToggleButton()
    {
        MyToggleButton.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyToggleButton)));
    }


    public Brush ToggledBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ToggledBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggledBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ToggledBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggledBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToggledBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
}
```

And in `Themes/Generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="border1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="5">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="Background" Value="{Binding ToggledBackground,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, build the actual window content using this toggle button. This is just a rough sketch of your desired UI, containing only the functional controls without labels and explanation:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="cb1"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsEditable="True"
                Margin="20"
                MinWidth="200"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TeaNames}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTea}">
            </ComboBox>
            <local:MyToggleButton
                x:Name="hotToggle"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsHotTea}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="20" MinWidth="60"
                Background="AliceBlue" ToggledBackground="Orange">
                <local:MyToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Cold"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hot"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </local:MyToggleButton.Style>
            </local:MyToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <local:MyToggleButton
                x:Name="milkToggle"
                Content="Milk"
                IsChecked="{Binding WithMilk}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="20" MinWidth="60"
                Background="WhiteSmoke" ToggledBackground="LightGreen"/>
            <local:MyToggleButton
                x:Name="lemonToggle"
                Content="Lemon"
                IsChecked="{Binding WithLemon}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="20" MinWidth="60"
                Background="WhiteSmoke" ToggledBackground="LightGreen"/>
            <local:MyToggleButton
                x:Name="syrupToggle"
                Content="Syrup"
                IsChecked="{Binding WithSyrup}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="20" MinWidth="60"
                Background="WhiteSmoke" ToggledBackground="LightGreen"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Notice the style trigger to change the button content between `Hot` and `Cold`.

Initialize the datacontext somewhere (eg. in the window constructor)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    grid1.DataContext = new TeaConfigurationViewModel();
}
```

At this point, you have a fully functional UI, it will work with the default mouse and keyboard input methods, but it won't yet support your shortcut keys.

So lets add the keyboard shortcuts without destroying the already-working UI. One approach is, to create and use some custom commands:

```
public static class AutomationCommands
{
    public static RoutedCommand OpenList = new RoutedCommand("OpenList", typeof(AutomationCommands), new InputGestureCollection()
    {
        new KeyGesture(Key.B, ModifierKeys.Control)
    });

    public static RoutedCommand ToggleHot = new RoutedCommand("ToggleHot", typeof(AutomationCommands), new InputGestureCollection()
    {
        new KeyGesture(Key.T, ModifierKeys.Control)
    });

    public static RoutedCommand ToggleMilk = new RoutedCommand("ToggleMilk", typeof(AutomationCommands), new InputGestureCollection()
    {
        new KeyGesture(Key.M, ModifierKeys.Control)
    });

    public static RoutedCommand ToggleLemon = new RoutedCommand("ToggleLemon", typeof(AutomationCommands), new InputGestureCollection()
    {
        new KeyGesture(Key.L, ModifierKeys.Control)
    });

    public static RoutedCommand ToggleSyrup = new RoutedCommand("ToggleSyrup", typeof(AutomationCommands), new InputGestureCollection()
    {
        new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control)
    });
}
```

You can then bind those commands to appropriate actions in your main window:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AutomationCommands.OpenList" Executed="OpenList_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AutomationCommands.ToggleHot" Executed="ToggleHot_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AutomationCommands.ToggleMilk" Executed="ToggleMilk_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AutomationCommands.ToggleLemon" Executed="ToggleLemon_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AutomationCommands.ToggleSyrup" Executed="ToggleSyrup_Executed"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

and implement the appropriate handler method for each shortcut in the window code behind:

```
private void OpenList_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(cb1, cb1);
    cb1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}

private void ToggleHot_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hotToggle.IsChecked = !hotToggle.IsChecked;
}

private void ToggleMilk_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    milkToggle.IsChecked = !milkToggle.IsChecked;
}

private void ToggleLemon_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lemonToggle.IsChecked = !lemonToggle.IsChecked;
}

private void ToggleSyrup_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    syrupToggle.IsChecked = !syrupToggle.IsChecked;
}
```

Again, remember this whole input binding thing is purely UI related, it is just an alternative way to change the displayed properties and the changes will be transferred to the viewmodel with the same binding as if the user clicks the button by mouse. There is no reason to carry such things into the viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer and your time. I'll try to refactor my project. Please answer again here (in comments) if I deal with the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, where is `xxx_Executed` methods must be declared? In `AutomationCommands` class?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I declared it in the Window class. It depends on, where the `CommandBindings` are declared. Since you probably want your shortcuts to work in the whole window, defining the command on window makes most sense.

Comment: in my case, the reaction of shortcuts is vary depending on windows, so I declare it in Window class, too.

Answer (score 1):

> how I can access to View controls from RelayCommand?

You shouldn't. The whole point of MVVM (arguably) is to separate concerns. The 'state' that the ViewModel contains is rendered by the View (controls). The ViewModel/logic should never directly adjust the view - as this breaks the separation of concerns and closely couples the logic to the rendering.

What you need is for the *view* to render how it wants to display the state in the View Model.

Typically, this is done by bindings. As example: Rather than the ViewModel grabbing a text box reference and setting the string: `myTextBox.SetText("some value")`, we have the view bind to the property `MyText` in the view model.

It's the view's responsibility to decide how to show things on the screen.

That's all well and good, but how? I suggest, if you want to do this change using styles like you describe, I'd try using a converter that converts the using a binding to ViewModel state (Say, an enum property `Hot` or `Cold`):

```
    <Button Content="Hot" 
        Tag="Hot"
        Click="ToggleTeaType" 
        Style="{Binding TeaType, Converter={StaticResource TeaTypeButtonStyleConverter}}"/>
```

Note, we're using WPF's bindings. The only reference we've got tot he view model is through it's property `TeaType`.

Defined in your static resources, we have the converter:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="HotTeaStyle"/>
        <Style x:Key="ColdTeaStyle"/>

        <local:TeaTypeButtonStyleConverter
             x:Key="TeaTypeButtonStyleConverter"
             HotStateStyle="{StaticResource HotTeaStyle}"
             ColdStateStyle="{StaticResource ColdTeaStyle}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

And have the logic for converting from the TeaType enum to a Style in this:

```
public enum TeaType
{
    Hot, Cold
}

class TeaTypeButtonStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Style HotStateStyle { get; set; }
    public Style ColdStateStyle { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TeaType teaType = (TeaType)value;

        if (teaType == TeaType.Hot)
        {
            return HotStateStyle;
        }
        else if (teaType == TeaType.Cold)
        {
            return ColdStateStyle;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

It could be made more generic and re-usable.

You should also take a look at toggle buttons, they deal with this kind of thing internally.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I'll try my best with putting into practice of your answer.

Comment: I think the other answer was the better solution for toggle buttons. But remember converters exist, they can be really useful in MVVM

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for the advice.